# Count number of elements meeting criteria in columns with NA values

Tags: r, sum, na

I've got a matrix with "A", "B" and `NA` values, and I would like to count the number of "A" or "B" or `NA` values in every column.

```
sum(mydata[ , i] == "A")
```

and

```
sum(mydata[ , i] == "B")
```

worked fine for columns without `NA`. For columns that contain `NA` I can count the number of `NA`s with `sum(is.na(mydata[ , i])`. In these columns `sum(mydata[ , i] == "A")` returns `NA` as a result instead of a number.

How can i count the number of "A" values in columns which contain `NA` values?

Thanks for your help!

Example:

```
> mydata
    V1  V2  V3  V4 
V2 "A" "A" "A" "A"
V3 "A" "A" "A" "A"
V4 "B" "B" NA  NA 
V5 "A" "A" "A" "A"
V6 "B" "A" "A" "A"
V7 "B" "A" "A" "A"
V8 "A" "A" "A" "A"

sum(mydata[ , 2] == "A")
# [1] 6

sum(mydata[ , 3] == "A")
# [1] NA

sum(is.na(mydata[ , 3]))
# [1] 1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function `sum` (like many other math functions in R) takes an argument `na.rm`. If you set `na.rm=TRUE`, R removes all `NA` values before doing the calculation.

Try:

```
sum(mydata[,3]=="A", na.rm=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is what you are after. RnewB too so check if this working.
Difference between the number of rows and your number of rows will tell you number of NA items.

```
colSums(!is.na(mydata))
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the answer from @Andrie,

```
mydata <- matrix(c(rep("A", 8), rep("B", 2), rep(NA, 2), rep("A", 4),
  rep(c("B", "A", "A", "A"), 2), rep("A", 4)), ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE)

myFun <- function(x) {
  data.frame(n.A = sum(x == "A", na.rm = TRUE), n.B = sum(x == "B",
    na.rm = TRUE), n.NA = sum(is.na(x)))
}

apply(mydata, 2, myFun)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to convert the column in a factor and then to use the function summary. Example:

vec<-c("A","B","A",NA)

summary(as.factor(vec))

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to do this is to do summary stats for the variable:

**summary(mydata$my_variable) of table(mydata$my_variable)**

This will give you the number of missing variables.

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

You can use `table` to count all your values at once.